# Custom Axes and Legends using D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, legend, axes

my data set is

```
var data = [
        [2010,"Internet",19],
        [2010,"Water",20],
        [2011,"Internet",36],
        [2011,"Water"‌​,44],
        [2012,"Internet",51],
        [2012,"Water",53],
        [2013,"Internet",39],
        [2013,"Water",30]
       ]

var allHeights = [-250,-215,-185,-140, -85, 40, 85, 140, 185, 215, 250];
var allColors = [
            d3.rgb(203,23,23),d3.rgb(108,74,246),d3.rgb(9,235,175),d3.rgb(159,172,38),d3.rgb(236,105,18),
            d3.rgb(137,195,95),d3.rgb(241,137,108),d3.rgb(253,233,127),d3.rgb(109,151,216),d3.rgb(15,199,58)
         ];
```

1. I want to draw a y-axis on the extreme right of the svg. The axis should be divided into points corresponding to "allHeights" and each point should be labelled with the
   year (i.e. data[i][0]).
2. I want to draw a legend for data[i][2] and fill each legend with allColors[i].

Please help

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far please?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind grouping year, title, and legend - but separating height and color? What about storing all linked data in the data array? Or maybe as JSON for readability?

Comment: My code so far 

`var width = 2000;
var height = 500;
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",width)
               .attr("height",height);
var group = canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(0,200)");
var yAxis = group.append("line")
       .attr("x1", 0)
                     .attr("y1", -200)
                     .attr("x2", 0)
                     .attr("y2", height)
                     .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                     .attr("stroke", "black");`
I want to break yAxis at heights from "allHeights" array and number them with data[i][0] from data.

Comment: sorry for the lack of indentation ... was really naive of me !!!

Comment: @JanneKlouman :- My aim is to draw circles with radius as data[2] and y-coordinate of the center of the circle as the height from allHeights. I will use the allHeights array to calculate the x-coordinate of the center. I will then fill each circle with color from allColors. I need a legend to mark data[1] as well.